# Auto ask to vote up question when we vote up answer

Tags: feature-request, up-votes

I read stuff a few weeks ago on Stack Overflow that it was important **to vote up questions too**. So, I've started doing it, each time I find the question that I was asking myself, I vote it up. But in fact, I remember to vote it up only when I vote up an answer. And, almost all the time, when I vote up an answer, I vote up the question.

So, I was wondering if it would be possible to make a system that, when we vote up an answer, asks us *"Would you like to vote the question"* or something like this, and we could click "yes" or "no".

Of course, it would show up only if we haven't voted up the question yet.

I think it would make me save about 2 seconds per question. I now it's not much, but as you have probably heard before, when you add this up, you realize that you save a lot of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Voting on a post should be done on that post's merit only, nothing else. Whether you vote on any answers to a question shouldn't have any influence on your likelihood to vote on the question.

A prompt to vote on a question, shown only when you vote on an answer, may help in your specific process in viewing Q&As but it isn't encouraging a desirable behaviour. It's instead creating an unintentional link between voting on answers and questions, which there shouldn't be.

> almost all the time, when I vote up an answer, I vote up the question

You must be lucky in seeing few low quality questions or voting up low quality questions. There are a lot of low quality questions, many of which have well written and thought out answers. Encouraging users to vote up regardless of post quality isn't a good idea.

If there was to be a notice (although I don't think there should be), it would need to be a *reminder* to vote—not an actionable prompt, and with *no indication of which way to vote*.

Comment: Why would you reject my edit and change just one out of 4 or 5 suggestions? I don't understand. It's your call, but I see some more mistakes in your answer.

Comment: Huh? I didn't even see a suggested edit never mind reject it...